# Python variable "declaration" in function body

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

```
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):    

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        viewMenu = wx.Menu()

        self.shst = viewMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Show statubar', 
            'Show Statusbar', kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
...
```

I've recently started  learning python and wxPython. The above code snipppet is from http://www.zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/ .
I'm trying to get my head around the *self.shst* variable. Why is it necessary to prefix it with the self keyword ?

From what I read, the self keyword is used in that context in the __init__ method, to "declare" instance variables, but the author has no *shst* declaration in __init__

**Edit**
In light of your answers I did the following test:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20
    def func(self):
        self.y = 10
    def getVal(self):
        return self.y


def main():
    t = Test()
    print t.getVal()
    print dir(t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am unable to access self.y in the getVal() function, and I don't see y in the output from dir(t). Shouldn't self.y be accessible to every function in the Test class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not prefix `shst` with `self.`, then it would just be a local variable that goes out of scope and is garbage-collected after the method exits.  There is no need to declare python class/object members prior to assignment.

Comment: you have not called `t.func()` which would create the `y` property.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Seems like a dangerous quirk of python, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There's no necessity to define instance variables in `__init__`. They can be defined anywhere. Python is a dynamic langauge, and it is possible to add attributes to an object at any point.

Comment: But isn't it good practice to define any used variable in `__init__`, because that way all internal variables used in the class can be seen in one function?

Comment: @Alex Indeed, but that's not enforced.